# Trigger Disable User

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem and question. The SQL trigger in my SQL Server has been disabled. And I want to learn who disable this triger. Is there any way to get username who disable MSSQL trigger? By SQL query or like that?
Regards.

Comment: Possibly. Depending on when it happened. See [Determining how a schema change occurred?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/10716/3690)

Comment: Though looks like Remus's answer on that question will be the only possible avenue if the default trace doesn't track this.

Answer (score 2):

If you have [sql server audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386.aspx) up and running then you can get that information. Otherwise no. Also read article [Auditing when Triggers are Disabled or Enabled for SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2802/auditing-when-triggers-are-disabled-or-enabled-for-sql-server/)

Comment: +1 I didn't realise this isn't captured in the default trace.

Comment: Thanks for reply shibormot (also M. Smith). I will go on research after read that article.